# How to have separate server configs for port 80 and 443 with ISPConfig

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using ISPConfig on Ubuntu. I want to have separate configs for port 80 and 443 but if I try to add a second server in ISPConfig it won't let me b/c I already have one of the same name.

And anything I add into 'nginx directives' under the Options tab goes in the server block already, so it's already listening on port 80.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do is copy the original configuration file to a save location so you can customize it. ISPConfig has a built-in conf-custom folder. When ever a file is places in there, having the same name as a server/system/ISPConfig config file, it gets overwritten:

```
    cp /usr/local/ispconfig/server/conf/nginx_vhost.conf.master /usr/local/ispconfig/server/conf-custom/
```

Now you can edit the copied file:

```
    nano /usr/local/ispconfig/server/conf-custom/nginx_vhost.conf.master
```

You'll find parts like this:

```
    <tmpl_if name='ssl_enabled'>
```

Everything in there will only be applied to SSL enabled sites. So you could create 2 "master blocks" like:

```
    <tmpl_if name='ssl_enabled'>
        (everything SSL goes here)
    </tmpl_else>
        (everything non SSL goes here)
    </tmpl_if>
```

That way, you can have two different ways ISPConfig creates the vhosts.

Comment: Obviously, @MaddinXx meant to group server block code in <tmpl_*> processing code blocks and that (as of ISPConfig 3.0.5.4) works to keep the ISPConfig process from throwing 'duplicate' errors when building the config from the (ispconfig/server/conf/*.conf.master) template.  But the 'else' block in his example above will drop one server block (:80) for the other (:443) if ssl_enabled.  And, it's not enough to 'enable' SSL in the domain tab, you have to generate a certificate in the SSL tab to get ssl_enabled to return a 1.